# Normal Fit from experimental data

Tags: python, normal-distribution

[image]

Hi all
I want to obtain a normal  fit from a set of data obtained from experimental results. Since i am starting with python, I dont know where to start. Here's my experimental data. Its a particle size distribution. I want to obtain mean and std. x is the size and y the frequency.

Thank you in advance for any help!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



x=([0.251839516,0.490440575,0.744647994,0.990643452,1.244142316,1.488611658,1.741274792,1.986416351,2.232538986,2.495993944,2.736393641,2.985059803,3.241792581,3.497435276,3.744829674,3.991788039,4.23860106])
y=([0.271164269,0.492366389,1.256781226,2.468772142,4.479769871,8.376708554,11.85803482,14.57231794,15.56056321,14.05547313,11.11227252,7.625604845,3.947070401,2.186355791,0.937144587,0.455061317,0.228687358])
plt.scatter(x,y,color='red',label='Experiment')
```

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177007/how-to-calculate-mean-mode-variance-standard-deviation-etc-of-output-in-pyth

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use SciPy you have [scipy.stats.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html):

```py
from scipy.stats import norm
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
```

Comment: norm.fit(data) doesnt work in my case, because i have two arrays. :(

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
from scipy.stats import norm as normalDist
x=([0.251839516,0.490440575,0.744647994,0.990643452,1.244142316,1.488611658,1.741274792,1.986416351,2.232538986,2.495993944,2.736393641,2.985059803,3.241792581,3.497435276,3.744829674,3.991788039,4.23860106])
y=([0.271164269,0.492366389,1.256781226,2.468772142,4.479769871,8.376708554,11.85803482,14.57231794,15.56056321,14.05547313,11.11227252,7.625604845,3.947070401,2.186355791,0.937144587,0.455061317,0.228687358])
points = list(zip(*(x, y)))
mu, std = normalDist.fit(points)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy.mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) and [numpy.std](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html)

```py
x = np.array([...])
x.mean()
x.std()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Gaussion Distribution can solve your question.

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
gmm.means_
gmm.covariances_
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).